# Woocommerce cookies are not getting stored once it reach the cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I m storing cookies using javascript it's working good and I am getting the data on checkout page. In case of adding two products in the cart I can only see cookie data until the first product added into the cart, when the second product comes in I can only see previous cookies new cookies which are stored while adding second product are missing.

Comment: Please, add your code, at least the relevant part.

Comment: var wpcart = justCallAjax(WPATH + 'cart?add-to-cart=' + wpProduct); This is how I am adding product to Cart. Once it's done. I need store new cookies which are not accessible in checkout

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are doing and edit your question with all the relevant code parts. Right now it isn't clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of store cookies using javascript or PHP Try use

```
wc_setcookie("cookieName", "CookiValue", $expire = 0, $secure = false);
```